# HTML Reset form including select element with selected='selected'

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a table page with html filters in a form at the top. When the form is submitted, the selected filters are applied to the SQL query, and the filters all gain selected='selected' on the value that was selected. I want a reset button that resets these to the first value of the selection, not that specified in the incoming code.

Does that make sense?

For example, if the HTML was :

```
<select name='minTV'>
<option value=0>Min TV 0</option>
<option value=1000>Min TV 1000</option>
<option value=1100>Min TV 1100</option>
<option value=1200>Min TV 1200</option>
<option value=1300 selected='selected'>Min TV 1300</option>
<option value=1400>Min TV 1400</option>
<option value=1500>Min TV 1500</option>
<option value=1600>Min TV 1600</option>
<option value=1700>Min TV 1700</option>
</select>
```

Now, when I hit the reset button, I want the first value, value=0, to be the selected one, not value=1300, as happens by default. I need to do this over several select boxes.

Any ideas? As simple as possible please.

No jQuery, but Prototype is fine.

EDIT, in response to answer #1:

I can't seem to get this one to work; my select is :

```
<select name='div' id='divSelect'>
<option value=0>All Divisions</option>
<option value=1 >Premiership East</option>
</select>
```

My reset button is:

```
<button type="reset"  value="Reset" onclick="return resetAll();">Reset</button>
```

And my javascript function is:

```
function resetAll() {
document.getElementById('divSelect').selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No jQuery, sorry - the site uses prototype. I'll try out the first suggestion presently.

Comment: The answer you were given works. Perhaps you have a syntax error, or your function is not declared? http://jsfiddle.net/1LrktwL5/1/

Comment: Also you mentioned you wanted to reset a lot of selects. I hope you select them by type or classname, rather than indivudally.

Answer (score 2):

You can give an id to your select tag for example id="selectbox" Then you can change the selected value with the following Javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('selectbox').selectedIndex = 0;
```

Note that you have to enter the number of the option, so for example for value=1000 you would enter selectedIndex = 1;

```js
function resetAll() {
document.getElementById('divSelect').selectedIndex = 0;
};
```

```html
<select name='div' id='divSelect'>
<option value=0>All Divisions</option>
<option value=1 selected>Premiership East</option>
</select>
<button type="reset"  value="Reset" onclick="return resetAll();">Reset</button>
```

[**see on JSFiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/1LrktwL5/1/)

Comment: Any chance you could take another look please mate?

Comment: Try this one: document.getElementById('divSelect').value = 0;

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('divSelect').selectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add some explanation about why your answer solves the OP's question?